# Could we together form a spiritual Temple?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

In relation to this question [Our bodies are our Temple?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74065/our-bodies-are-our-temple) I wondered if it's possible to form a spiritual Temple of some kind out of the Jewish community?

Could we together form a dwelling place where HaShem can live in our midst, and if so how do we build such kind of place (environment)?

Comment: In [Tanya chap 33](http://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1029025/jewish/Chapter-33.htm) you find (edited) 

When one will deeply contemplate this, his heart will be gladdened and his soul will rejoice with joy and singing, with all heart and soul and might, in [the intensity of] this faith which is tremendous, since this is the [experience of the] very proximity of G‑d, **and it is the whole [purpose] of man and the goal of his creation, as well as of the creation of all the worlds, both upper and lower, that He may have an abode here below,** ...etc

Answer (score 1):

Our sages tell us that when a quorum of Jews gather together and learn or pray can cause the Divine Presence to rest upon that group. See this [discussed in detail here](http://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7968/jewish/Epistle-23.htm).

This is similar to the Beit Hamikdash, where the Divine Presence dwelt.

See too the statement of the Sages in [Brachos 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=pdf):

> Abbaye says: At first I would love in the house and pray in the shul. Since I heard the statement of Rabbi Chiya Bar Ami in the name of Ula, "From the day that the Beit Hamikdash was destroyed The Holy One Blessed Be He only has in this world the 4 Amot (cubits) of Halakha", I only davened where I learned.

Answer (score 0):

In the Avot de Rabbi Nathan 4a is a teaching that tells us both humans and the temple are made out of the two hands of G-d, because its said of humans:'*Your hands made me and fashioned me* (Tehillim 119:73).' And its said of the Temple: '*Your habitation, which You made, O Lord; the sanctuary, O Lord, which Your hands founded* (Exodus 15:17).'

So the comparison has been made before, but rather used in a different context.